The meaning of Pinata
‘It’s funny,’ says David Ellefson, ’cos you watch Some Kind of Monster
and people are talking about, “Oh and then they had a therapist.” I’m like,
gimme a fucking break! [In Megadeth] we had, like, four therapists!’ He
laughs. ‘I’m like, fucking been there, done that, lived that movie. In fact,
that’s the one thing we beat Metallica to. We fucking beat ’em with group
therapy!’ Says Alexander Milas, ‘I remember when I first watched it,
getting really emotional. Metallica by that point had become such a pinata,
for me as a journalist but also as a fan, it was always that thing of: oh, it
was all better before the Black Album, that’s where it ended – with Cliff. All
of a sudden they were revealed to be human beings with flaws and
emotions. And I actually began to like Lars Ulrich again. It resurrected my
love of Metallica, as a band of the present and not just as a relic of the
Eighties. At the same time, I was pretty shocked that they did it. It was
almost like they were committing an act of supreme penance toward their
fans.’
What does Pinata mean here? Thanks

What is a pinata (according to the dictionary).  If the literal meaning doesn't work, don't you think it might be metaphor?

I would prefer to write piñata, because it's a Spanish word, pronounced 'peenyata'. It's a figure of speech, meaning roughly 'a thing that people love to hit', hence 'a frequent object or victim of ongoing criticism or abuse.' - a real piñata in Spanish-speaking parts of North, Central, and South America is a paper animal full of candy hung up at parties. Children whack it with sticks to make the candy fall out.

It annoys me (a bit) when Gringos in my country (UK) say 'peena colada'.

They are common in non Spanish speaking North America too.
